# Timber Not Logging in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, timber-android

Timber is a great library for logging in Android. In Kotlin classes though, doesn't output anything. How can I fix this?

MainActivity.kt code:

```
Timber.e("Timber Log 1")
Log.e("MainActivity", "Log 1")
```

Gradle: 
I've tried the regular Java Timber:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
```

And this Kotlin specific wrapper:

```
implementation 'com.github.ajalt:timberkt:1.5.1'
```

Same result. No output with either. Only from the `Log.e()`

Answer (score 37):

The first step of Timber is to plant the tree as [mentioned in docs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber)

> Behavior is added through Tree instances. You can install an instance
>   by calling Timber.plant. Installation of Trees should be done as early
>   as possible. The onCreate of your application is the most logical
>   choice.

And use the `debugTree`

> The `DebugTree implementation will automatically figure out from which`
>   `class it's being called and use that class name as its tag`. Since the
>   tags vary

If you don't do this then you will have no logs entry and do this as soon as possible, like in `oncreate` or better inside application class so do this

```
Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree());
```

Comment: Ah jeez, I got so wrapped up in the Kotlin I forgot to initialize the logger. Thanks a lot!

Comment: as you guys already know, it's `Timber.plant(DebugTree());` in kotlin, missed the kotlin tag

Comment: @IliaSidorenko 'cause it's catchy!

Answer (score 28):

I have faced same problem, using Kotlin and Android studio 3.6
Follow these steps:

1. Add the following in build.gradle(Module: App)

   ```
   implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
   ```
2. Initialize `Timber` in Application Class:

   ```
   class MyApp : Application() {

       override fun onCreate() {
           super.onCreate()

           if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
               Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the Application class(`MyApp`) to the Manifest (AndroidManifest.xml)

   ```
   <application
       android:name=".MyApp"
   ```

Now you can use Timber: `Timber.i("Timber logs")`

Also can use custom tags if you wish: `Timber.tag("Yo").I("used custom tag for logs")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, literally the one I was searching for!

Comment: Adding android:name=".MyApp" to manifest is crucial, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was wrong BuildConfig import

```
import org.koin.android.BuildConfig
```

but my app has

```
import com.company.example.BuildConfig
```

Comment: It was import androidx.viewbinding.BuildConfig in my case, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Probably late to the party but my problem was the my phone was set to "Charge only" and not "file transfer". Apparently I was allowed to build and run, but logs were blocked

EDIT Another solution:

Check your RUN tab in the bottom of Android Studio. Sometimes the logs get output to there instead

Answer (score 1):

**Check Initialization:** Ensure that you've properly initialized Timber in your application. It's usually done in the `onCreate` method of your `Application` class.

```
   class MyApplication : Application() {
       override fun onCreate() {
           super.onCreate()
           if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
               Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
           }
       }
   }
```

Just make sure you are importing `BuildConfig` from the correct location.
The correct way is: should be configured appropriately in your project's `Gradle files` for example `import com.example.appname.BuildConfig`.
If it still does not work, try `import androidx.viewbinding.BuildConfig`

Remember to make sure that your app's build configuration is set up correctly in your `build.gradle` files to ensure that `BuildConfig.DEBUG` behaves as expected. Debug and release configurations should be configured appropriately in your project's Gradle files.

Ensure that there is no space between the words in the tag. Otherwise, the tag you add to logcat will only display according to the first word. Briefly, space is not counted by logcat.